# matlab converting adjacency matrix to adjacency list

Tags: algorithm, matlab, matrix

I have a large sparse adjacency matrix with around **10M nodes**, which I am processing with MATLAB. I want to convert the matrix into adjacency list as efficiently as possible. As an example adjacency matrix to illustrate this:

```
adj =
     1     0     1
     0     0     1
     0     1     1
```

And the output is:

```
ans =
     0     0     2
     1     2
     2     1     2
```

I want to do it as efficiently as possible, is there any efficient way to do it?

Comment: A sparse matrix is going to be a better representation of an adjacency list than anything you would transform this to. The one thing to remember is that matrices in MATLAB (including sparse) are column-major, so you should orient your matrix accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The result needs to be a cell array of vector, because the number of nodes connected to each node varies. Here's a way to do it:

```
[ii, jj] = find(adj); % row and col indices of connections
y = accumarray(ii, jj-1 , [], @(x){sort(x.')}); % get all nodes connected to each node,
    % sorted. Subtract 1 for 0-based indexing
```

This gives

```
>> celldisp(y)
y{1} =
     0     2
y{2} =
     2
y{3} =
     1     2
```